# magento attributes in db

Tags: mysql, magento, entity-attribute-value

I'm in the process of migrating our Magento 1.3.2.2 store to another platform. I'm trying to get all of the product attributes that are stored as text values.

I can't figure out which table this data is held. I've looked everywhere it seems. I have the db diagram from Magento's website, but it's not helping me.

Thanks.

It turns out what I was looking for was:

```
catalog_product_entity_varchar
where eav_attribute.is_user_defined=1
```

Comment: EAV Attributes?  Non-configurable product options?  Being explicit about what information you're after is crucial to getting a good Magento answer.  Where in the admin can you see the information you're after?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know what the correct terminology is. In the admin area they are called attributes under the catalog. I found it under catalog_product_entity_varchar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phrase

> get all of the product attributes that are stored as text values

is unclear.  However, here's how you can track down where **any** information is stores in a LAMP stack application.

In a development environment (i.e. your local machine):

Dump your database out to disk using the old, individual insert format

```
mysqldump --skip-extended-insert -h db_server -u mysql_uname -p magento_db_name > before.mysql
```

In the application, change the value of the data you're looking for.

Dump your data out to disk again

```
mysqldump --skip-extended-insert -h db_server -u mysql_uname -p magento_db_name > after.mysql
```

Using your favorite diff tool, diff the database dumps.

```
diff before.mysql after.mysql
```

This will point out extra inserts needed after your operation, which in turn will let you know which tables contain the information you're after.

Comment: I'm looking for the attribute values. I'll try your method though.

Comment: Actually I think I can just use phpmyadmin for search, because I'm working of a dump and not a magento site.